# Is possible load a custom activity on journey with another webservice and not heroku?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, custom-activity

I've created an app and uploaded it on Heroku and works great but I need to upload it on Cloudfront but when I do it I'm getting this error bellow.

Inspecting the browser I can see that journey is trying to reach an url that doesn't exist, it get my url an add `/confi.js` at the end of the url.

[image]

Comment: When you configure your custom activity in your installed package, you provide your "Endpoint URL". Journey Builder expects to find your config.json and index.html file on that path. Eg: if your Endpoint URL is "https://myapp", Journey Builder expect your config.json to be at "https://myapp/config.json" and your UI to be available at "https://myapp/index.html".

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answer, but it`s trying to reach myurl/config.js without reason because it really don`t exist what exist is my config.json, to satisfy the requisition I turned my config.json in config.js e it works, at least stoped to get error 404 but my app is not rendering at screen on journey builder yet. any advice?

Comment: Hello, how did you solve the issue at the end ? I am having the exact same problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you secure your webapplication ?
I understand your issue of config.js getting called.

SFMC behaviour:

1. JB checks for config.json
2. If it doesn't get the json file, it loads fallback method for finding config.js

Check your Network traces once to make sure that your config.json is not getting blocked.

Also your console.logs will show error message "failed to load config.json for url and attempting to load legacy config.js"

My suggestion would be to check,

1. When you try to hit your config.json url in web browser is it loading perfectly?
   ex: https://mywebapp/config.json
2. If it doesn't still please check your file structure for index.html and config.json

PFB sample structure.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sharath, thanks for answer, that`s the exactlly structure, I`m facing this trying to upload it on a cluster of kubernete, my mistake talking about cloudfront initially, when I upload it on Heroku, it work`s.

On kubernete I had to upload config.js and this issue is solved, now after fill my app on journey builder and click done firing a payload.arguments and triggering 'updateActivity event' returns the payload with full filled fields that I asked for, but when I activate the journey returns this error bellow

Check to ensure that the activity orentry source publishes to a validendpoint

Comment: Upon Activation, it calls your validate and publish endpoints again. So can you please check by validating your Journey before activating. 
If it throws error while validate, you need to check response from your validate api (via postman). You need to get 200.
If it throws error for activate, you need to check response from your publish api and then execute api (via postman).
Seems like your api is not giving proper response. Please check if JWT is passed correctly too.